# XCode std::string_view auto at global namespace failure

Tags: c++, xcode, global, auto

I'm using some global pre-calculated constexpr strings to work with types. The function I'm building is:

```
// strfindCExpr and strlenCExpr are my constexpr methods for string manipulation

template<typename T>
static constexpr std::string_view getTypeName() {
    constexpr auto p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    constexpr auto pStart = strfindCExpr(p, strlenCExpr(p), "= ", 2) + 2;
    constexpr auto pEnd = strfindCExpr(pStart, strlenCExpr(pStart), "]", 1);
    return {pStart, pEnd - pStart};
}
```

Generally this function produces the values correctly when called with different types, i.e. `getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>() == "NSA::BlackList"`

The problem I run into is when I try to use these constexpr at the global namespace.

Working version:

```
constexpr std::string_view myType = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
// myType == "NSA::BlackList"
```

Not working:

```
constexpr auto myType = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
// myType == "der/Folder/Folder/File.cpp"
```

Funnily enough, when I print out typeid(myType).name(), in both versions they end up with: NSt3__117basic_string_viewIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEE .

Using XCode version 9.4.1, Apple LLVM 9.0

This is a runtime issue:

```
constexpr std::string_view myTypeWorking = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
constexpr auto myTypeNotWorking = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();

int main() {
    assert(strncmp(myTypeWorking.data(), "NSA::BlackList", strlen("NSA::BlackList")) == 0); // Ok
    assert(strncmp(myTypeNotWorking.data(), "NSA::BlackList", strlen("NSA::BlackList")) == 0); // Fail
    constexpr auto myTypeLocalWorking = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
    assert(strncmp(myTypeLocalWorking.data(), "NSA::BlackList", strlen("NSA::BlackList")) == 0); // Ok
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Compilation, linking, runtime error? Can you make it into a [mcve]?

Comment: At runtime, the values are not equivalent

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question and add that info and make it into a [mcve] so that others can try it out?

Comment: First - kudos for the interesting method! Second - I did not face the same result, please consider my answer!

Comment: It's still not a complete example. Put something up that we can compile as-is.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I run into is when I try to use these constexpr at the global namespace.

There is not as much detail in the question as I would like, but this provides a clue.

I'm guessing that `getTypeName` is defined in some namespace other than the global namespace? Let's suppose that namespace is `types`.

If that is the case, the name of this template is actually `types::getTypeName<>`.

To call it from the global namespace you'd have to write something like:

```
constexpr auto myType = types::getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
```

or

```
using namespace types;
constexpr auto myType = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
```

or

```
using types::getTypeName;
constexpr auto myType = getTypeName<NSA::BlackList>();
```

Comment: Updated to make it more clear by what I mean in that sentence. I mean that ```auto``` variables in a local scope are computed correctly. Global scope operates differently for some reason.

Comment: you're going to have to post an MCVE I'm afraid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: I also think @DarthZaloj is using the right scope operators. I think the problem is some thing else!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that, by compiling (*GCC 8.3.1 20190223* with *-std=c++2a* under *Linux*) and execution of a redacted version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
namespace name1{
template<typename T>
static constexpr std::string_view getTypeName() {
    return {__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ + 58, 18};
}
}// namespace name1
namespace name2{
template<typename>
class sample{};
}// namespace name2
namespace name3{
template<typename T>
static constexpr std::string_view getTypeName() {
    return name1::getTypeName<T>();
}
}// namespace name3
template<typename T>
static constexpr std::string_view getTypeName() {
    return {__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ + 51, 18};
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view myType1 = name1::getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    constexpr auto myType2 = name1::getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    constexpr std::string_view myType3 = name3::getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    constexpr auto myType4 = name3::getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    constexpr std::string_view myType5 = getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    constexpr auto myType6 = getTypeName<name2::sample<int> >();
    std::cout << myType1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myType2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myType3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myType4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myType5 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myType6 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which examines different cases, I got this output:

```
name2::sample<int>
name2::sample<int>
name2::sample<int>
name2::sample<int>
name2::sample<int>
name2::sample<int>
```

I guess maybe the problem is with the compiling environment/implementation.